# Finding newest or flagged row in a one to many relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the title is poor, I'm trying to do a join from a primary table to a related table and only return a single row that matches a flagged or the most recent row in the related table.

Primary table, let's call it group, has columns:

```
id, name
```

Related table, let's call it user, has columns:

```
id, group_id, email, default, updated_datetime
```

The query should return a single 'group', and either the matching record from 'user' with default=1 (preferred), or if no rows have default=1 then the row with MAX(updated_datettime). 'user' will have 1-n rows with group.id = user.group_id.

Example result:

```
group.id, group.name, user.email, user.default, user.updated_datetime
1, 'test', 'email', '0', '2015-06-10 12:00'
2, 'other', 'email', 1', '2015-06-08 10:00'
```

Both tables contain a lot of data so I'd prefer to do this with join's and not subqueries. I know how to do it with subqueries but I'm having trouble doing it with joins since the grouping has multiple conditions.

I'm fine with doing aliases, eg:

```
select a.* from (query) as a
```

I'm trying to avoid subqueries in the main select, eg:

```
select group.id, group.name, (query) as user.id
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to use 2 joins and a `IF()` in your select to select the default user or the last updated user.
Then, because you want to join using a `MAX()` condition, you will need subqueries.

Something like that should get you on the right track:

```
select group.id, if(default_user.id is not null, default_user.id, last_updated_user.id) as user_id
from group
left join user default_user on default_user.group_id = group.id and default_user.default = 1
join (
  select user.* from (
    select group_id, max(updated_datetime) as updated_datetime from user group by group_id
  ) as max_per_group join user using(group_id, updated_datetime)
) as last_updated_user on last_updated_user.group_id = group.id
```

But note that this isn't a fast query, and if you need to do it frequently, you might want to refactor your tables. For example, you could add foreign keys `default_user_id` and `last_updated_user_id` in the `group` table.

Comment: I hadn't considered tracking the preferred ID in the primary table, that's easy enough I'll run with that thank you!